# greek letters not shown in Xquartz- R- Mac issue?

Tags: r, macos

I have a Mac (running on High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199)) and use R (R 3.5.0 GUI 1.70) for analysing my data. As a biologist I am using greek letters such as µ really regularly. In my script I can nicely write µ and others but once I plot the graph I get exactly two dots instead of my letter. So for example µg will be written as ..g
I of course checked already my script on other computers. My windows computer does write µg on the axes- using the EXACT same script. My colleague also has a Mac and she is also able to use my script and produce nice greek letters. Can anyone help me or might have an idea on what is wrong with my Mac?

Thats how I my piece of code with µ looks like:

```
mtext(text=expression('content [µg egg'^-1*']'), side =2, line=5, cex=1)
```

or

```
mtext(text=expression('δ'^15*'N'), side =2, line=3, cex=2)
```

Comment: My guess would be encoding/locale issue. Can you compare those?

Comment: Paste the word mu....

Comment: mtext(text=expression(paste('content [‘, mu_g, ‘egg'^-1*']')), side =2, line=5, cex=1)

Comment: thanks for your advice- unfortunately they didn't work out. However I finally managed with this code, that I would like to share: mtext(text=expression(paste("content [", mu, "g ", egg^-1, "]")), side =2, line=5, cex=1)